# Yandex API создает 2 разных маршрута по одному адресу

Tags: javascript, yandex-geocoding-api

Работаю над функционалом расчета стоимости доставки. В пределах КАД фиксированная стоимость, а за его пределами тарифная за каждый километр. По примерам из Яндекс песочницы, соединил в один скрипт 2 варианта :

1. https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator
2. https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/route_inside_polygon

Логика скрипта должна была быть следующая:

Из поля адрес пользователем вводится адрес, и создается маршрут от склада до введенного адреса. Далее скрипт разбивает этот маршрут на отрезки и красит их в зависимости от нахождения в полигоне. Далее, если введенный адрес находится за пределами КАД, то находим координаты, где заканчивается КАД и координаты адреса. Начинаем расчет длины пути от этих двух координат.

И вот вроде бы работает, но почему-то не проходит проверка, чтобы отрисовать путь, если адрес введен в пределах КАД, и по некоторым адресам отображается 2 разных маршрута. Как так получается, и как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var DELIVERY_TARIFF = 40,
    MINIMUM_COST = 1200,
    suggestView1 = new ymaps.SuggestView('delivery_adress', {
        results: 5
    }),
    routeTo,
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [59.941574, 30.347597],
            zoom: 9,
            controls: []
        }), 
        routePanelControl = new ymaps.control.RoutePanel({
            options: {
                // Добавим заголовок панели.
                showHeader: false,
                title: 'Расчёт доставки',
                visible: false
            }
        }),
        zoomControl = new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({
            options: {
                size: 'small',
                float: 'none',
                position: {
                    bottom: 145,
                    right: 10
                }
            }
        }),
        finalRouteStart,
        finalRouteEnd,
        finalRoute,
        kadPolygon;


    suggestView1.events.add("select", function(e) {
        routeTo = e.get('item').value;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/wp-content/themes/shablon/kad.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: onPolygonLoad
        });
      })
    // Пользователь сможет построить только автомобильный маршрут.
    
    myMap.controls.add(routePanelControl).add(zoomControl);

    function onPolygonLoad (json) {
        myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();
        kadPolygon = new ymaps.Polygon(json.coordinates);
        // Если мы не хотим, чтобы контур был виден, зададим соответствующую опцию.
        kadPolygon.options.set('visible', false);
        // Чтобы корректно осуществлялись геометрические операции
        // над спроецированным многоугольником, его нужно добавить на карту.
        myMap.geoObjects.add(kadPolygon);
        

        routePanelControl.routePanel.options.set({
            types: {auto: false}
        });



        ymaps.route([[59.963499,30.463677], routeTo]).then(
            function (res) {
                // Объединим в выборку все сегменты маршрута.
                var pathsObjects = ymaps.geoQuery(res.getPaths()),
                    edges = [];
                    
                // Переберем все сегменты и разобьем их на отрезки.
                pathsObjects.each(function (path) {
                    var coordinates = path.geometry.getCoordinates();
                    
                    for (var i = 1, l = coordinates.length; i < l; i++) {
                        edges.push({
                            type: 'LineString',
                            coordinates: [coordinates[i], coordinates[i - 1]]
                        });
                    }
                });
                

                // Создадим новую выборку, содержащую:
                // - отрезки, описываюшие маршрут;
                // - начальную и конечную точки;
                // - промежуточные точки.
                var routeObjects = ymaps.geoQuery(edges)
                        .add(res.getWayPoints())
                        .add(res.getViaPoints())
                        .setOptions('strokeWidth', 4)
                        .addToMap(myMap),
                    // Найдем все объекты, попадающие внутрь КАД.
                    objectsInPiter = routeObjects.searchInside(kadPolygon),
                    // Найдем объекты, пересекающие КАД.
                    boundaryObjects = routeObjects.searchIntersect(kadPolygon);


                // Раскрасим в разные цвета объекты внутри, снаружи и пересекающие КАД.
                boundaryObjects.setOptions({
                    strokeColor: '#06ff00',
                    preset: 'islands#greenIcon'
                });
                objectsInPiter.setOptions({
                    strokeColor: '#ff0005',
                    preset: 'islands#redIcon'
                });
                // Объекты за пределами КАД получим исключением полученных выборок из
                // исходной.
                routeObjects.remove(objectsInPiter).remove(boundaryObjects).setOptions({
                    strokeColor: '#000000',
                    preset: 'islands#blueIcon'
                });
                finalRoute = routeObjects.remove(objectsInPiter).remove(boundaryObjects),
                finalRouteStart = finalRoute.get(0).geometry.get(1),
                finalRouteEnd = finalRoute.get(finalRoute.getLength() - 1).geometry.getCoordinates();
                
                

                if (routeObjects.getLength() == objectsInPiter.getLength()) {
                    console.log('Попал в функцию InKAD');
                    getDistanceInKAD();
                } else {
                    console.log('Попал в функцию OutKAD');
                    getDistanceOutKAD();
                }

                
                
            }
        );

            function getDistanceOutKAD() {
                routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({
                    fromEnabled: false,
                    from: finalRouteStart,
                    to: finalRouteEnd
                 });

                routePanelControl.routePanel.getRouteAsync().then(function (route) {

                // Зададим максимально допустимое число маршрутов, возвращаемых мультимаршрутизатором.
                route.model.setParams({results: 1}, true);

                // Повесим обработчик на событие построения маршрута.
                route.model.events.add('requestsuccess', function () {

                    var activeRoute = route.getActiveRoute();
                    if (activeRoute) {
                        // Получим протяженность маршрута.
                        var length = route.getActiveRoute().properties.get("distance"),
                        // Вычислим стоимость доставки.
                            price = calculate(Math.round(length.value / 1000)),
                        // Создадим макет содержимого балуна маршрута.
                            balloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                                '<span>Расстояние: ' + length.text + '.</span><br/>' +
                                '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Стоимость доставки: ' + price + ' р.</span>');
                        // Зададим этот макет для содержимого балуна.
                        route.options.set('routeBalloonContentLayout', balloonContentLayout);
                        // Откроем балун.
                        activeRoute.balloon.open();
                    }
                });

                });
                function calculate(routeLength) {
                    return Math.max(routeLength * DELIVERY_TARIFF + MINIMUM_COST);

                }
            }
            function getDistanceInKAD() {
                
                routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({
                    fromEnabled: false,
                    from: 'Санкт-Петербург Шоссе Революции 88 Ж',
                    to: routeTo
                 });

                routePanelControl.routePanel.getRouteAsync().then(function (route) {

                // Зададим максимально допустимое число маршрутов, возвращаемых мультимаршрутизатором.
                route.model.setParams({results: 1}, true);

                // Повесим обработчик на событие построения маршрута.
                route.model.events.add('requestsuccess', function () {

                    var activeRoute = route.getActiveRoute();
                    if (activeRoute) {
                                         
                        // Вычислим стоимость доставки.
                         var   price = 1200,
                        // Создадим макет содержимого балуна маршрута.
                            balloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(                            
                                '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Стоимость доставки: ' + price + ' р.</span>');
                        // Зададим этот макет для содержимого балуна.
                        route.options.set('routeBalloonContentLayout', balloonContentLayout);
                        // Откроем балун.
                        activeRoute.balloon.open();
                    }
                });

                });
                
            }
        
        /*уmaps.route([finalRouteStart, finalRouteEnd]).then(function (route){
            var distance = Math.round(route.getLength() / 1000);
            console.log(distance);
        })*/
    }
}
```

Comment: А страницы с минимальным рабочим примером кода у вас не найдётся? Маршруты должно быть несложно ограничить одним через параметр results:1, если я правильно понял ситуацию. А вот что за проверка не проходит - непонятно.

Comment: @YaCor' рабочий код тут https://okna-spb.ru/test-setka-page/index.html

Comment: Вы строите несколько маршрутов, насколько вижу. А какой в итоге оставить-то хотите, раз говорите, что нужен один? А проверка... не проще ли конечную точку просто проверить через objects.searchInside(), ведь полигон-то у вас уже есть? Так, как это сделано на примере Яндекса - https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/show_visible_objects

Comment: @YaCor' Маршрутов несколько, потому что по примеру https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/route_inside_polygon не начнет делать расчёт стоимости доставки, потому что не возвращает данные о дистанции, для этого простраивается другой маршрут уже от кад и до адреса через routePanel, вопрос в том, что почему они такие разные?

Comment: Теперь понял - речь не о нескольких маршрутах на карте, а об отличии исходного трека и полученного при построении пути от КАД. Так бы сразу и сказали. Ну строго говоря Яндекс нигде и не обещает одинаковых результатов при разных исходных данных. А сами маршруты от исходной точки получаются практически одинаковой длины тут (38км), а какой из них выберет маршрутизатор - как повезёт, а на стоимость влиять не должно у вас. Так что просто скройте исходный маршрут

Comment: @YaCor' спасибо за наводку